# Chain rule for dependent functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

Consider the following equations:

$$R=\frac{dU}{dx} +5U\tag{1}$$
$$U=f(x) \tag{2}$$

Which of the following statements is the correct way of calculating the total derivative of R?

$$R=R(U(x),x) \rightarrow \frac{dR}{dx}=\frac{\partial  R}{\partial  U}\frac{d U}{d x}+\frac{\partial R}{\partial x}\tag{a}$$

$$R=R(U(x)) \rightarrow \frac{dR}{dx}=\frac{d  R}{d  U}\frac{d U}{d x}\tag{b}$$

And is there a way to calculate $\frac{\partial  R}{\partial  U}$ or $\frac{d  R}{d  U}$ implicitly without substituting equation 2 into equation 1?

Comment: What depends on what? You seem to say $U$ depends only on $x$ and $R$ is its derivative, then $\frac{dR}{dx}$ is just $\frac{d^2 R}{dx^2}$. I see no reason from what you have said why you would use any chain rule at all.

Comment: That is the question, I want to use the chain rule and I simplified the problem here.  Imagine the function f to be a complicated subroutine on a computer, and R to be a more complicated and nonlinear differential operation on U. Then, the chain rule needs to be used.

Comment: But it isn't a function of $U$ in the setting you gave, so there is no way to use the chain rule in any reasonable sense here. You have to give a simplified setting that has the same basic features as your actual setting. Simply put: on what does $R$ explicitly depend? Is it $x$? Is it $U$ and $x$? Is it $U$ and $x$ and also some derivatives of $U$? In all of these cases you get the same result: $\frac{dR}{dx}=\sum_i \frac{\partial R}{\partial y_i} \frac{dy_i}{dx}$ where $y_i$ are all the variables that $R$ depends explicitly on, and where $\frac{dy_i}{dx}$ are also total derivatives.

Comment: To your last question, it depends on what kinds of notation you are willing to accept.  Following the notation in "Expanding the Algebraic Manipulability of Differentials": $ \frac{dR}{dU} = \frac{d\left(\frac{dU}{dx}\right)}{dU} + 5 \frac{dU}{dU} = \frac{dx\,d^2U - dU\,d^2x}{dU\,dx^2} + 5$.